# Do massive conformal field theories exist?

Tags: conformal-field-theory

The only examples of conformal field theories I have found by googling seem to be massless. The most basic being the free boson. Can someone just leave a simple example of a massive conformal field theory I can look at? I mean something really simple.

If they don't exist can someone tell me why in very simple language?

Comment: As a slogan, the lack of massive CFTs is because "[conformal invariance] can only hold if the theory has no preferred length scale. But this means that there can be nothing in the theory like a mass or a Compton wavelength." (From p. 2, [chapter 4](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/string4.pdf) of Tong's lectures on string theory.) For a more technical discussion, see the answers at [Why is conformal invariance only possible for massless theories?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270088/55904) over at MathOverflow.